# Combination of SpamAssassin and Spamhaus SBL are incorrectly marking emails with company links as spam

Tags: spamassassin

My email signature has a link to my company website and it's formatted correctly.  If someone replies to an email I sent them, very often SpamAssassin marks the *reply* as spam.  I'm also getting reports that my emails land in recipients' junk folders.

Here's the relevant part of the header in a reply to my email:

URIBL_SBL_A Contains URL's A record listed in the Spamhaus SBL * blocklist * [URIs: (the domain)] * 1.6 URIBL_SBL Contains an URL's NS IP listed in the Spamhaus SBL * blocklist * [URIs: (the domain]

Here's the thing:  my domain is *not* listed on the Spamhaus SBL.  When I look up my domain on the Spamhaus SBL lookup it reports "(the domain) has no issues."

So, essentially, Spamassassin is marking my emails as spam because I have a link to my website in my signature and that link is *apparently* on the SBL list, but in reality it's not.  There's no way that I know of to contact Spamhaus about this.  Any ideas?  Thank you in advance.